# Organized outdoor backpacking tours in Europe/Asia/Africa?

Tags: hiking, nature-and-wildlife, backpacking

Not long ago I started doing backpacking occasionally with Russian tour agencies. Typically the tour here is a 5 to 14 day walk in some remote parts of the country either along official tracking routes or just some common tourist route in a wild area. 90% of the time we sleep in tents, sometimes in organized shelters, cook on either open fire or a gas burner. The agency usually advertises the route, consults tourists, forms a group and provides two tour leaders.

There are literally hundreds of such tours from Russian agencies, some from Ukrainian, but I could not find any from Europe/Asia/Africa at all. Most of the time it's plain hiking -- sleep in hostels/hotels, carry only a light backpack with what you need for a day trip.

So the question is whether there is organized backpacking agencies? Maybe any hint on how to find them (googling backpacking trips just doesn't seem to work even for Russia)? Maybe, that's just not a really popular activity in the region?

Comment: I think the walking holiday (you could call it track or tour) I did in Norway is in the same spirit, although we did have to carry our things, no roads on the Hardanger Vida. It was (then) organized through a Dutch holiday company. I doubt they still run this kind of tour.

Comment: Have you looked at NOLS?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "trekking".  Backpacking in English is more about low-cost travel to tourist spots: staying in hostels, overnight trains, bars and parties etc.

Comment: Don't the Russian agencies offer trekkings abroad? In the Netherlands, I know of 3 such agencies that organize trekkings all over the world. Unfortunately their target audience is dutch only, so they don't have English websites.

Comment: @Berend sure most of the Russian agencies provide service abroad, but most of the time it's either the Lycian Way or ex-USSR, or something really distant, like Argentina or Nepal. Also I'm really curious to try trekking in multicultural environment. Still thanks for the info on local dutch agencies, resembles the situation in Russia: businesses targeting local audience only.

Comment: They exist but get rather expensive. With a wildlife focus, Naturetrek in the UK are one example (I've travelled with them but not on a trekking trip), Wildlife Worldwide also offer some trips (again, used them but only for a self-drive trip with guided day-hikes). Mentioned as examples but I'd use either again for travelling long-haul (these days I try not to fly, and holiday on a lower budget, even aside from restrictions).  I have heard of group treks where you only carry day-kit.  Googling *trekking [destination] bag transfer*  produces a good few hits for *UK* or *Mont Blanc* as examples.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but as it stands it's a bit close to a shopping request - or an answer based on my comment would look that way.  I reckon it could be made less so, so no close vote (yet) from me.

Comment: BTW as far as I'm concerned, this sort of thing is best done self-guided through clubs rather than commercially, hiring bag-transfer services which also exist if you really don't want to carry everything

Comment: @ChrisH-UK that was extremely helpful! Googling the words you proposed really does the trick (only for hut-to-hut hikes though, so still looks like trekking with tent is not a popular option).

Comment: @VladimirNazarenko I think have the tents transported for you falls into a gap between hut-to-hut, and carrying the tents, which means you don't need road access to your camping spots (subject to local laws).  I've done both, even had single trips which were a mixture.  I have come across *cycling* trips in the UK where tents were carried and erected for you each day - and they were riding shorter daily distances than I would fully laden plus paying nearly 10x as much as it cost me